# unable to render java script in chromium browser in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, chromium

while trying to render a simple java script file to print fibonacci table ,I am getting nothing (a blank page) in chromium... as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> The Fibonacci Numbers </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("<h2>Table of Fibonacci Numbers</h2>");
    for(i=0;j=1;k=0;f=0;i<50;i++;f=j+k;j=k;k=f) {
        document.write("Fibonacci("+i+") = "+f);
        document.write("<br>");
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought may be this is because javascript is not enabled in chromium ,,so I searched and ran...

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

but ,It didn't worked ??
what is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with Chrome, nothing to do with Java (what IcedTea is a plugin for, which is very much *not* Javascript). The problem is simple: **Your syntax on that `for` loop is *all* wrong.**

```
for(i=0;j=1;k=0;f=0;i<50;i++;f=j+k;j=k;k=f) {...}
```

A simple iterator `for` loop like this (there are other sorts of for loop) should read like:

```
for (declaration; limit; iterator) {
    code
}
```

I can sort of see what you're attempting, you just need to rearrange it:

```
j=1;k=0;f=0;
for(i=0;i<50;i++) {
    f=j+k;j=k;k=f;
    document.write("Fibonacci("+i+") = "+f);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Oli ,I should have written for(i=0,j=1,k=0,f=0;i<50;i++,f=j+k,j=k,k=f) instead ..

Comment: @jazzz Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should :) If it isn't a functional part of the loop, don't include it in the loop definition. It just makes it harder to read.

Comment: yeah @Oli ,that's right ,,I got it .for sake of readability :)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Ubuntu, you just have a syntax error in your script. Next time, open the javascript console (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>). You will see this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Firefox with FireBug installed is a little more helpful:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control
for(i=0;j=1;k=0;f=0;i<50;i++;f=j+k;j=k;k=f) {
--------------^
```

As far as I know, you can't do all that in the `for` loop declaration but I'm no JavaScript expert so I may well be wrong. What is certain is that you can't do it *that* way. For example, where do you change the value of `j`? Even if that worked, it would always print `0`. What you're looking for is something like

```
<html>
<head>
<title> The Fibonacci Numbers </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.write("<h2>Table of Fibonacci Numbers</h2>");
    document.write("Fibonacci(0) = 0<br>");
    document.write("Fibonacci(1) = 1<br>");
    last=1;
    BeforeLast=0;
    for(i=2;i<50;i++){
        f=last+BeforeLast;
        document.write("Fibonacci("+i+") = "+f);
        document.write("<br>");
        BeforeLast=last;
        last=f;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx@terdon..well it was a C/C++ mistake actually, nothing to do with ubuntu .. sorry!!